# Need to use PayPal for user signup

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, crowdsourcing

I'm planning to build a Crowdfunding platform like [Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/) using [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) for my final year project. I have only 7 days left for that. I tried reading PayPal documentation but still I don't know how to integrate PayPal in to my website.

**What I need to know**

- Users to login in to my site using PayPal
- Name, Date of Birth, Address, E-Mail of user from PayPal API Server
- Additionally Pre-Approval Adaptive Payment for backing projects posted in my crowdfunding platform

**What I have**

- PayPal developer account with `PayPal payments` and `Log In with PayPal` enabled for live transactions
- Basic account at [Janrain](http://janrain.com/) and [oneall](http://www.oneall.com/). Using Janrain I added `login with PayPal` button in my site. After user login using PayPal, PayPal redirected to the `return URL` that I specified and from that URL I got only this `array(3) { ["login_tab"]=> string(6) "paypal" ["expected_tab"]=> string(6) "paypal" ["welcome_info_name"]=> string(10) "username" }` by  var dumping `$_REQUEST`

Can anyone please give me step by step guidance to complete this project.

Answer (score 0):

First Step:

Never decide to integrate PayPal into your project with CodeIgniter(which is no longer maintained) 7 days before it is due. PayPal is not all that good on docs last time I checked and if you have no experience with a Payment API(which I assume you don't given you said 7 days to do it...) You should pick a different end of year project for sure.